# Какие есть способы реализации очистки страницы на FastCGI сайте?

Tags: c, fastcgi

Хочу сделать калькулятор с помощью libfcgi. Какие есть подходы к очистке страницы после получения первых данных от сервера с помощью printf?

Comment: а чем может быть «загрязнена» в браузере свежесозданная страница?

Comment: Второй printf ничего не выводит - как исправить?